# Equivalent of DocumentSnapshot in Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

DocumentSnapshot is for Firestore right? Is there any equivalent of DocumentSnapshot in Firebase RealTimeDatabase? Becasue i'll use it in my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for recyclerview items to have an onclcick events on each items.

Answer (score 0):

A `DocumentSnapshot` in Firestore is a snapshot of the data in a document, which is the basic unit of data storage in that database.

The equivalent on Firebase's Realtime Database would be a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot), which contains the data for a node - the basic unit of data storage for *that* database. `DataSnapshots` are also what the [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) in the [FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) uses to track the current snapshots of the data.